# How to iterate all object in data section?

Tags: vue.js

I have data that look like:

```
data: 
  {
   main_level:
   {  
    user_input_1 : 
    {
     isFilled : false,
     val_1 : null,
     val_2 :null,
     val_3 : null,
    },
    user_input_2 : 
    {
     isFilled : false,
     val_1 : null,
     val_2 :null,
     val_3 : null,
    }
   }
}
```

I want to create method that will iterate it, and print `user_input_1`, `user_input_2` objects. How to do it? I tried:

```
methods: {
  myclick: function () {
   for (el in Object.values(this.main_level))
   {
    console.log(el)
   }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `Object.keys`:

```
for (el in Object.keys(this.main_level))
```

If you need both the key and value, you can use `Object.entries`:

```
for (el in Object.entries(this.main_level))
```

```js
var data =  {
   main_level:
   {  
    user_input_1 : 
    {
     isFilled : false,
     val_1 : null,
     val_2 :null,
     val_3 : null,
    },
    user_input_2 : 
    {
     isFilled : false,
     val_1 : null,
     val_2 :null,
     val_3 : null,
    }
   }
}

console.log(Object.keys(data.main_level))
```

Comment: I am getting digits on console instead of nested objects

Comment: Are you using single file component? In which case, your `data` needs to be a function. Try `data () { return { main_level: ... } }`

Comment: My data is placed in: `var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: 
  {`

Will `user_input_1` in your answer is object, or just a text? I need object

Comment: Then may be your `main_level` is an array instead of Object. If that is the case, then you can try `for (el in this.main_level) { console.log(Object.keys(el)[0]) }`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, just change the for-loop from **in** to **of**:

`el in Object.values(this.main_level)` to `el of Object.values(this.main_level)`

Here is a working example:

```
methods: {
  myclick: function () {
    for (obj of Object.values(this.main_level)) {
      console.log(obj)
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j0pd1q2z/